# How to copy/paste conditional formatting in Google Sheets (without including the original cells)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

When I copy and "paste the conditional formatting only" option from one column to another (e.g. A1:A5 to B1:B5) the result is that for B1:B5 the conditional format range includes A1:A5.

How can I paste the conditional formatting to have a standalone range that only includes B1:B5? (excluding the laborious way of redefining it).

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0):

First use the copy command `Edit`-->`Copy`
You can then use a special paste for this as shown in the image.

`Edit`-->`Paste special`-->`Conditional formatting only`

[image: paste the conditional formatting only]

Comment: Yes that is known, but does not cause: "to have a standalone range that only includes B1:B5" ; for it will also include A1:A5 into the range.

Comment: *"for it will also include A1:A5 into the range"* It will and it makes perfect sense. Because - since you paste a new range- it will include both ranges.